# Multiple controllers and views with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need help to create multiple views and controllers with same name.

For solve the problem of controller, I did it:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Leads",
        url: "Leads/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Project.Controllers.Leads" });

    // Default route.
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "Project.Controllers" });
```

But I need help to create a multiple views with same name.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: Hi, I have a area of "Admin", I need two controllers with the name "Home" and in each controller must be created an action "Index".

Comment: Just right click and select Add View in the Index method of the corresponding controllers. MVC will create the Index view file in the corresponding Area automatically

Comment: Is this giving you the wrong view or no view at all?

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem. I was creating the folder "Leads" in directory "Controllers", when should I be creating within the directory "Areas". Thanks a lot. :)